# Kentico 9 cms:cmsTextBox placeholder localization

Tags: kentico

I've duplicated the search box webpart so i can make changes. I'm trying to add a localization string to the placeholder attribute.

This isn't working:

```
<cms:CMSTextBox ID="txtWord" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" MaxLength="1000"
  ProcessMacroSecurity="false" placeholder="<%= CMS.Helpers.ResHelper.GetString("kff.Search--PlaceHolderCopy")%>" />
```

nor does this:

```
<cms:CMSTextBox ID="txtWord" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" MaxLength="1000"
  ProcessMacroSecurity="false" placeholder='<%= CMS.Helpers.ResHelper.GetString("kff.Search--PlaceHolderCopy")%>' />
```

I have a JS Snippet that does work, but i'm hoping to avoid copy in JS files.

```html
  var $searchField = $('.searchTextbox');

  if ($('body').hasClass('ENCA')) {
    // search field placeholder copy      
    $searchField.attr('placeholder', 'Search For Stuff');
  }
  else {
    $searchField.attr('placeholder', 'Recherche');
  }
```

Can I add the localization string to the server tag, or should it be done in the code behind. I'm not sure the best location in the code behind for this either, I can't see a Page_Load block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following line in the `SetupControl` method in the codebehind:

```
txtWord.Attributes.Add("placeholder", ResHelper.GetString("kff.Search--PlaceHolderCopy"));
```

You cannot really use the `<%=` syntax to set properties of server-side controls.

Also, please note that the `CMSTextBox` control has a `WatermarkText` property, which might be what you are looking for. It uses the `TextBoxWatermarkExtender` control from the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx) library.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Would be nice if this was added to the base control.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to duplicate the webpart and have duplicate code just for something this simple.  Just create a different [webpart layout](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Using+custom+web+part+layouts) for that webpart and add the following code above the Panel:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        txtWord.Attributes.Add("placeholder", ResHelper.GetString("yourstring"));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I agree, but i have other small changes. I set the visibility to hidden for the CMSButton and the image button. I added a DIV so i could use FontAwesome as the search icon.


I didn't want to risk anything due to a hotfix.

Comment: `code`    <div id="searchBtn" class="btn" onclick="<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>.click()" role="button">
     <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
     <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
    </div>

Comment: A hotfix or an upgrade will not cause problems with a custom webpart layout.

Comment: I should have mentioned this isn't on a portal page. I have the webpart on a .Master page.

Comment: Yes, that's where I put my search webparts, doesn't matter either way.